# Manually uploading files to Firebase storage and adding it to Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have an app that all it does is to present PDF documents that is stored in `Firebase`.

I've created a collection in Firestore with all the relevant information for the documents (title, description etc.) and all is left to do is to provide a download URL to the PDF itself.

I've uploaded the PDF manually to Firebase Storage, but I couldn't find a way to manually copy the file URL in order to paste it in the Firestore.

How can I add the URL for the files **Manually**? (My client doesn't write code and he needs to update the files constantly).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply click the link shown in the picture below, then copy the URL it directs you to.

[image]

Comment: That was easy. Thank you